# How does require(../) in node.js work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What modules does node.js look for when it encounters var foo=require(../) ?

It would seem that it would look in the directory one UP from the current one, but what exactly would it look for and do?

Perhaps there is an analogy with **include** in C or **import** in Python?

I've been starting with node.js and reading
http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html
and came upon example code on github such as

```
var express = require('express')
  , tracker = require('../')
```

This code would seem to assign variable *express* contents of express module (file) whose path must be global after using npm to install express, that much seems understandable,although I understand there are two types of module installation, but that is another question.

But what contents are assigned to variable *tracker*?

Comment: `express` does not have to be a globally-installed module, this `require` style usually [loads it from the `node_modules` directory](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders). My guess is that `require('../')` would [look for a `package.json` in the directory](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules) above the current module's directory, though I have no idea under what circumstances it would find one there.

Comment: Checkout [Folders as Modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules) for `require('../')`, [Loading from `node_modules` Folders](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) for `require('express')`, and `npm`'s [folders(1)](https://npmjs.org/doc/folders.html#tl-dr) for "*I understand there are two types of module installation.*"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on WHAT is in that directory.

**If X begins with './' or '/' or '../'**:

a. LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)
b. LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(Y + X)

**LOAD_AS_FILE(X):**

1. If X is a file, load X as JavaScript text.  STOP
2. If X.js is a file, load X.js as JavaScript text.  STOP
3. If X.node is a file, load X.node as binary addon.  STOP

**LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(X):**

1. If X/package.json is a file,
   a. Parse X/package.json, and look for "main" field.
   b. let M = X + (json main field)
   c. **LOAD_AS_FILE(M)**
2. If X/index.js is a file, load X/index.js as JavaScript text.  STOP
3. If X/index.node is a file, load X/index.node as binary addon.  STOP